# Runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 wasn't downloaded. Try to run a NuGet restoration with RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-x64'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a self hosted web API for an Android device.

Here is the main content of my csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFrameworks>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
    <Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-$(Platform)</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>android-$(Platform)</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
</Project>
```

1. When I build for x64, I get this compilation error:

> NETSDK1 - Runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 wasn't downloaded. Try to run a NuGet restoration with RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-x64'. - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets

It doesn't make sense since linux it's not a target framework.

2. When I build for x86, I get this compilation error:

> NETSDK1 - There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x86'. - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets

Is it possible to build a web API hosted on Android?